# How to catch http connection errors in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, dns, interceptor

I have a bunch of `$resource`s set up. There are cases when the API server I'm using to get them times out or it's domain name cannot be resolved. Those are expected cases.

How can I catch those errors in AngularJS? I have tried setting up a `$http` interceptor, but it's not really verbose.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $rootScope) {
    return {
        responseError: function(rejection) {
            console.log(rejection);
            if(rejection.status <= 0) {
                $rootScope.$emit('httpConnection:error', rejection);
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
});
```

The console outputs

```
GET http://my.api/api/endpoint.json net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
Object {data: null, status: -1, config: Object, statusText: ""}
```

Notice the `status: -1` and `statusText: ""`.

I'd like to have an indication regarding that `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error. Is there any way I can receive that error in the `responseError` handler parameter?